# Filling calendar in run time

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

I have a `list of teachers`, inside this list I have a `sublist with disciplines`.
I need to create something like a `week calendar` to show the disciplines of the clicked/selected professor. These disciplines have an data-atribute to identify the day of the week and the time it starts.

Like so:

```
 <li data-day="Monday"data-time="08:30:00"> Database Fundamentals</li>
```

Here is how the list/sublist are:  [Codepen.Io](http://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/YqxNjv)

So I need to insert this discipline on `Monday, starting: 8:00:00` I can also add another data attribute to know the ending time later.

What I don't know is this:

For now I'm using `FullCalendar`(Couldn't find any better for my situation).
I'm writing some events manually just for tests like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>      
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calendario</title>       
    <script src='calendario/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='calendario/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script src='calendario/lang/pt-br.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='calendario/fullcalendar.css'/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date = new Date();
        var dia = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth()+1; //January is 0
        var mes = m < 10 ? '0' + m : '' + m;
        var ano = date.getFullYear();
        var data = ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia;


        //Page is now ready, initialize calenda.
        $('#calendario').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                center: 'title',
                left: '',
                right: ''
            },          

            height: 800,
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',  

            views: {
                week: {
                    columnFormat: 'dddd'
                }
            },

            firstDay: 1,
            weekends: false,

            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Event1',
                    start: ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia,
                    end: ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia + 'T04:00'
                }
            ],

        })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="teste">
        <div id="calendario"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have to write the events inside the `<scrip>` on the header. HOW could I add more events in Run Time?  When I toggle the professor, I'd like to add all the subitems to the calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});
});

$('#addEvent').click(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    'renderEvent',
    {
      title: 'Novo evento',
      start: '2016-03-31',
    }
  );
});
```